Minimum value of $m$ such that $n$ queens can be placed on the chessboard without attacking each other on $m\times n$ chessboard

This question is not from a live contest!!!
This question is from IMO National Selection Test 2 (also called IMONST2) year $2023$ for Malaysia, Junior paper question $6$. This is the official website, and this is the last year paper.


Question: Fix an integer $n\ge 1$. On $m\times n$ chessboard, what is the minimum value of $m$ such that $n$ queens can be placed on the chessboard without any two attacking each other? (A queen can attack vertically, horizontally, or diagonally across any distance.)

For me, I have no much attempts to this question, and would like some helps.
My attempts:
I have no ideas, so let’s do from small cases.
First, I know that $m\ge n$. If $m\lt n$, then some queens will be attacked each other.
If $n=1$, then $m=1$.



If $n=2$, then $m=3$. (The “X” is where we put the queens)



If $n=3$, then $m=4$. (The “X” is where we put the queens)



If $n=4$, then $m=4$.



If $n=5$, then $m=5$.



If $n=6$, then $m=6$.



If $n=7$, then $m=7$,



If $n=8$, then $m=9$. (Ignore the black cross, see the blue cross)



If $n=9$, then $m=10$.



Do I need to continue with the cases? How to prove the results?

Check out $n=8$ first before you try to show that this construction will always work :-) Also this.

Your solution for $n=8$ is wrong, check the diagonals.

@caduk Help me to check the $n=8$ case, and should I continue writing the cases?

Clearly, $~m \geq n,~$ since if $~m < n,~$ and (for example) there are $~m~$ rows and $~n~$ columns, then you can only have 1 queen per row.  Based on this 8 queens puzzle article, $~m = n.$

This is a classic problem know as the Eight queens puzzle. The answer is that for $n\ge 4$, you have solutions for $m = n$.

I understand already, thanks everyone.
